# are there any limitations in the IsolatedStorageSettings in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a question about the `IsolatedStorageSettings` in WP7.

normally i parsed all my Lists etc with json and then saved it to a `IsolatedStorageFile`. but now i'm asking myself why i'm doing this. isn't is easyer simply to save the lists etc to the `IsolatedStorageSettings`?

does the `IsolatedStorageSettings` have any limitations about the size? these are no lists with 100000 entries.

or is there any argument against these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsolatedStorageSettings was not developed to hold large quantities of application data like you propose.  While you *may currently* be able to store data there, there is no guarantee that future updates won't fundamentally change the way this area works, thereby exposing yourself to risks about your app's function.

It is probably advisable, therefore, to stick with using the "normal" IsolatedStorageFile techniques you said you already use.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, none at all. As long as your phone has > 10% of storage space you can do whatever you want. Who cares about everyone else's applications.

If the user says O.K. to the warning message then you can save more, but it could cause the application to crash